# locate a file by date and extension

Tags: command-line, bash, files, find, locate

I was writing a program in C, or C++, on my work computer on Friday, September 23rd, 2016. I forgot the name of it, and where I put it. I was writing it in Geany, but its an older version on Geany, and it is amnesiatic, about old files (I forgot about that problem).

How can I search by the day, and file extension to locate the file I have wrote? It took me all day to write, and I wouldn't like to rewrite it

Comment: use find - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-ctime` option to find, but it is relative to now rather than to date... You could combine tests to get the right time, for example:

```
-ctime +48 -and -ctime -72
```

would test for files that were last modified some time between 48 and 72 hours ago (when was Friday? What day is it? I can't count... It's late in my timezone) (and we don't *really* need `-and` since that is implied, but it helps me to think clearly!)

Something like this, assuming it's in your home directory somewhere...

```
find ~ -type f -ctime +48 -and -ctime -72 -iname "*.cpp"
```

(replace `cpp` with whatever the extension was, if not that)

Comment: Yeah Found it!!!

Comment: Hahaha sweet ^_^